# Extracting Data Only Return Quote '' (Imacros)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, imacros, data-extraction

Hi I want to extract data from this website: taobao.com
The only thing I need is to extract **data-id** attribute value in each item in a shop.
I will give example the datasource refers to file with this:

```
https://shop122418146.world.taobao.com
https://shop68989753.world.taobao.com
```

Here's what I've tried.

```
const L = "\n";
const numLines = 3;


/* --------------------- main --------------------- */
for (x = 1; x <= numLines; x++) {
        iimPlayCode (
                'SET !DATASOURCE E:\\XXX\\Taobao\\TaobaoShop.csv' + L +
                'SET !DATASOURCE_LINE ' + x + L +
                //'SET !REPLAYSPEED MEDIUM' + L
                'URL GOTO={{!COL1}}' + L +
                'WAIT SECONDS=1' + L +
                'EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML" KEYS="[40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40]"' + L +
                'WAIT SECONDS=1' + L
            );
    for (y = 1; ;y++) {
        iimPlayCode (
                'TAG POS=' + y + ' TYPE=DL ATTR=CLASS:item* EXTRACT=data-id' + L
            );
        if(iimGetLastExtract()=="#EANF#"){
            break;
        } else{
            iimPlayCode (
                'SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}\\Taobao\ FILE=Taobao.csv' + L +
                'SET !EXTRACT NULL' + L
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it could be easy to make it work, but it only return like these

```
""
""
""
""
...
```

Any suggestion to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Aha!
I am trying another approach using match() method and it works seamlessly.

```
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/-*[0-9]+/)")
```

Comment: But this leave me question,
does imacros add on for firefox can't be used to extract value from attribute ***directly*** ? While we need to instead extract the HTML then extract necessary data.